# Filling a dataframe with elements from another dataframe and perform calculation

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to fill column ['A'] of df1 with the 1st column of df2 and perform a (5 year) rolling compound growth calculation. But when I run below code the computer is getting into an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
for ind in df1.index: 

    while len(df1.index) >(6+ind): 
        amount_start= df1.iloc[0+ind,0]
        amount_end = df1.iloc[6+ind,0]    
        df2['A'][ind] =((amount_start/amount_end)**(1/5))-1
```

----------------------update-----------------------------

So just to explain a bit better. I have a multi index dataframe with different tickers for different years and want to get for each ticker a new CAGR column (3y in this example. The code posted by Akshay works fantastic, but since it was only for one ticker I changed it to a groupby method,  but now I cant manage to attach the series to my Dataframe. What is the best way to do this?. I have attached a screenshot below.

windows = df.groupby('Symbol').rolling(1+3)
df2 = windows['Revenue'].apply(lambda x: (x.iloc[0]/x.iloc[-1])**(1/3)-1)

[CAG_3y][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgeNK.png

Comment: Maybe that there is nothing in your while loop that changes the value of ind so it will never exit.

Comment: Please provide an expected output thanks! Please read [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What exactly is the calculation you want to do?

The value of ind never changes, it's always 1.

P.S. You should probably edit your question as I'm pretty sure it's the (random) values in df1 you want to copy to df2 and not the zeroes in df2 to df1.

Comment: @norie, i am a bit confused by what you mean `ind never changes`. There is a loop that modifies the `ind` value as a value between 0-14. `for ind in df1.index: `. Do clarify, thanks!

Comment: The issue seems to be inside the `while` loop where `ind` doesnt change and remains equal to 0, infinitely. Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you just want to apply the CAGR formula to rolling windows of size 5, then you can use `pd.Series.rolling()` or its dataframe variant. check my answer for details.

Comment: Yes, the value of ind  never changes in the inner loop. Thought it's value is always 0 not 1 as I stated in my original comment.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://i.imgur.com/cmmFuNm.png).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are trying to calculate compound growth, over rolling windows of size 5.

[image]

#### Rolling windows for a single column

Is this what you are trying to achieve?, If yes, then you can use `pd.Series.rolling()` to apply your CAGR function on rolling windows of a column/Series.

```
windows = df1.A.rolling(5)
df2.A = windows.apply(lambda x: (x.iloc[0]/x.iloc[-1])**(1/5)-1)
df2.A
```

```
0          NaN
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
4     0.203404
5     0.100237
6     0.308324
7    -0.099169
8    -0.234710
9    -0.045973
10   -0.167447
11    0.218108
12    0.272260
13    0.043961
14   -0.234327
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

#### Rolling windows for all columns

The great part about rolling method is that it's also available for data frames as `pd.DataFrame.rolling()`, which can apply to all columns at once.

```
windows = df1.rolling(5)  #df1 instead of df1['A']
windows.apply(lambda x: (x.iloc[0]/x.iloc[-1])**(1/5)-1)
```

[image]

> Note: The `inf` values are because of the 0s that you generate randomly in dataframe as denominators. The `Nan` values are the values that don't have enough prior window size to compute the cagr. But you can avoid that if you want with some paramters in the `rolling()` method.

---

#### Detailed functioning

Looking at the original, first, last, and compound value of the column with rolling windows -

```
d = {'original A':df1.A, 
     'first': df1.A.rolling(5).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0]),
     'last': df1.A.rolling(5).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]),
     'first/last': df1.A.rolling(5).apply(lambda x: (x.iloc[0]/x.iloc[-1])),
     '(first/last)^power': df1.A.rolling(5).apply(lambda x: (x.iloc[0]/x.iloc[-1])**(1/5)),
     'CAGR': df1.A.rolling(5).apply(lambda x: (x.iloc[0]/x.iloc[-1])**(1/5)-1)
    }

pd.DataFrame(d)
```

[image]

Comment: I finally understand your answer and it works great, but what if my dataframe also needs to be sorted not only by year but also by ticker? . Can I use groupby ?


Ticker year         rev         CAGR?
ticker1 2009 1000
ticker1 2008 750
ticker1 2007 600
ticker1 2006 500
ticker1 2005 400
ticker1 2004 440
ticker1 2003 300
ticker1 2002 100
ticker1 2001 90
ticker2 2008 22
ticker2 2007 45
ticker2 2006 56
ticker2 2005 23
ticker2 2004 10
ticker2 2003 5
ticker3 2019 400
ticker3 2018 440
ticker3 2017 300
ticker3 2016 100
ticker3 2015 90
ticker3 2014 80

Comment: You can sort the data frame after this by using `df.sort_values(['col1','col2'])`. Read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for more details.

Comment: Also, its difficult to make sense of data posted in comments. Can you post this into the original question?